# Is it possible to enable Autonomous Database's DBMS_CLOUD pls/sql package in an on-prem Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, oracle-autonomous-db

Is it possible for my team to use the DBMS_CLOUD PL/SQL package in a non-ADB database, on-premise or running over a VM in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBMS_CLOUD  in  PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference

Yes, this is now possible! You will need to manual install the DBMS_CLOUD package.
The package is supported in Oracle Database 19c beginning with 19.9, as well as in Oracle Database 21c beginning with 21.3.

[Here is the MOS note](https://support.oracle.com/cloud/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=302349351285134&_afrWindowMode=0&id=2748362.1&_adf.ctrl-state=13v72qw10v_4), updated by Oracle, to manually install the DBMS_CLOUD package on an Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes DBMS_CLOUD package can be installed in 19c as well as 21c on-premises databases.

There is a nice detailed blog to follow the office MOS note from Oracle -
https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/dbms_cloud-installation